# Dispatch Click Event to <canvas> Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, canvas

I am trying to trigger a click event on a `<canvas>` element using jQuery. My code is simple: find the correct canvas element and then call `.click()`.

For example: `$("canvas").eq(0).click();`

However, the programmatic click does not produce any activity, such as how a manual mouse click does on this specific `<canvas>` element. I have no information about how the canvas was drawn (obfuscated JavaScript). Does getting the `<canvas>` element to respond to `.click()` require knowing which event listeners are tied to the content in the canvas?

EDIT: More concretely, I am trying to invoke a click event on the waveform `<canvas>` element on SoundCloud. When clicked manually, the sound seeks to the position indicated by the mouse click. I cannot reproduce this click onto the  element programmatically.

Comment: What does _a manual mouse click_ do in your project?

Comment: Can you provide a demo os the issue?

Comment: rtfm. http://api.jquery.com/click/   and   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events